# Unable to download website content with wget

Tags: html, bash, download, wget

I am failing to download the below website using wget in bash:

```
wget --wait 1 -x -H -mk https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=usdt-btc&type=sell
```

I have found some similar issues in other questions, however, their solution was to use `-mk`, which makes no difference here. The prompt just freeze after the command and nothing happens. If I try to open the same website in a browser, it will open normally. I would be grateful for any help here.

Comment: Quote your url! (especially the `&` character is special to the shell).

Comment: Very primitive mistake. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment, you need to quote your URL.

The `&` in the URL is putting `wget --wait 1 -x -H -mk https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=usdt-btc` into the background and causes everything after the `&` to be interpreted as a command, **which can be a great risk** depending on the URL!

If your URL contains a `$` you should use single-quotes (`'`) to pass the string literally without variable expansion, otherwise double quotes (`"`) are fine.